# Reduce vertical spacing when using `\underset` and `\overset`

Tags: math-mode, spacing, stacking-symbols, overset

Trying to use notation of the form `(a, b)\underset{{+}}{\bumpeq}(c, d)`, I find the combined symbol `\underset{{+}}{\bumpeq}` too much spread vertically for my purposes:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$(a, b)\underset{{+}}{\bumpeq}(c, d)$
\end{document}
```

How can the vertical spacing in `\underset` and `\overset` be controlled?

Comment: Could you please post a complete compilable code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a low level alignment tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bumpeqplus}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bumpeq@{+}}}
\newcommand{\bumpeq@}[2]{%
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th#1\bumpeq$\cr % top
      \noalign{\sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mkern2mu$}\kern-\wd\z@}
      $\m@th\alexey@demote{#1}#2$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\alexey@demote}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
(a, b)\bumpeqplus(c, d)_{x\bumpeqplus y}
\]

\end{document}
```

Change `2mu` after experimenting some values (always in `mu` units).

[image]

In case you need also other symbols instead of `+` you can define other commands, for instance

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bumpeqminus}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bumpeq@{-}}}
```

and nothing else is required.

Comment: Hi, visually I think in subscript mode the size of the symbol created looks too big to me.

Comment: @Sebastiano The proportions seem the same. I don't really like the symbol, to be honest.

Comment: ahahaahh..also for me...But does this symbol is used? :-( Never I have seen this notation. It reminds me of the rank of second officer when I was in the Italian Navy.